# Get title from object closest to date, django model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have to models:
**Week:**

```
class Week(models.Model):
    week_id = models.Charfield(unique=True, null=False, primary_key=True)
    year = models.PositiveSmallInteger()
    weeknumber = models.PositiveSmallInteger()
    ...
```

and
**Deadline**

```
class Deadline(models.Model):
    deadline_type = models.CharField()
    end_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)
    week_id  = models.ForeignKey(Week, related_name='deadlines', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   ...
```

Which gives me an output like:

```
{
    "weeknumber": 1,
    "leaflet_year": 2019,
    "week_id": "01_2019",
    "deadlines": [
        {
            "deadline_type": "Some Deadline type",
            "end_at": "2019-10-23T14:00:00Z",
        },
    ...
    ]
}
```

What I want to achieve, is to annotate the Week object with the `deadline_type`of the deadline object which have the `end_at`closest to today.

I can annotate the end date, but I simply have no idea on how to get the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do like this using [subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.models.db import Subquery, OuterRef


deadline = Deadline.objects.filter(week_id=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('end_at')

weeks = Week.objects.all().annotate(closest_deadline_type=Subquery(deadline.values('deadline_type')[:1]))
```